# Not data on new array poolList when use axios, but console.log still have data

Tags: node.js, api, express, axios

I got trouble when creating API using axios. The new array received no contain data but when I run console.log(response), it shows data (see image attach). Anyone can help me for this issue

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const pools = [
        'pool1',
        'pool2',
    ]
    const poolList = pools.map(async pool => {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://example.com/pools/${pool}/summary.json`)
        console.log(response)
        return {
            response
        }
    })
    res.send({
        poolList
    })
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RaVD.png)

Comment: Try `Promise.all(poolList).then(res.send)`. You may also want `return response.data` in your map callback

Comment: I tried your comment but it's still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Its because of async in `pools.map(async pool => {`. The expected
result of `poolList` is an array of promises.

try to await all

```
const pools = [
    'pool1',
    'pool2',
]
const poolList = await Promise.all(pools.map(async pool => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://example.com/pools/${pool}/summary.json`)
    console.log(response)
    return {
        response
    }
}));


res.send({
    poolList
})
```

Comment: I tried your comment but it's still the same issue :((

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Your `poolList` is an array of promises. You're then trying to respond with these promises as JSON. This will look something like the following because when promises are stringified, they become empty objects

```js
{
  "poolList": [{}, {}]
}
```

#### Solution

What I suspect you actually want is the following...

```js
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const pools = [
    'pool1',
    'pool2',
  ]

  try {
    const poolList = await Promise.all(pools.map(async pool => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`https://example.com/pools/${encodeURIComponent(pool)}/summary.json`)
      return data // resolve with the data, not the full Response object
    }))

    res.json({ poolList })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    res.status(500).send(err)
  }
})
```

This creates an array of promises that resolve with the remote data (each `summary.json`) and waits for each of those promises, resulting in an array of data.

This will respond with something like

```js
{
  "poolList": [
    { /* pool1/summary.json */ },
    { /* pool2/summary.json */ }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It returned a 404 error as below `{message: "Request failed with status code 404"}
message: "Request failed with status code 404"`

Comment: @TADA that probably means at least one of your `summary.json` URLs is incorrect

Comment: yeah, I got it, thanks Phil a lot, your suggestion is great :3